# Hide dialog box after hiding block

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a script to delete data with ajax. After clicking the delete link, a confirmation box appears.

When I confirm, the box is hidden and after that , the div that contains the deleted data also hides.

I'd like that the div that contains thé deleted data be hidden first then hide the box.

```
// this div will be hidden
<div id="remove-item{{entity.id}}" >

    <a class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw fa-2x  remove_item" href data-entity-id="{{ entity.id }}">
               </a>

</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".remove_item").click(function () {
            var entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id'); //
            var removeItem = '#remove-item-' + entityId; // the div
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color: brown"></i> Confirm',
                message: 'Delete ?',
                className: 'my-class',
                buttons: {
                    cancel:{
                        className: 'btn btn-default',
                        label: 'Close'
                    },
                    success: {
                        className: 'fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger',
                        label: ' Delete',
                        callback: function(){

                        $.ajax({
                           type: 'POST',
                           dataType: 'json',
                           url: Routing.generate('travel_delete_ajax', {'id': entityId }),
                           success: function () {
                              $(removeItem).hide(); // hide the div
                           }
                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide the div *prior* to opening the dialog:

```
    $(".remove_item").click(function () {
         var entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id'); 
         var removeItem = '#remove-item-' + entityId; 

         $(removeItem).hide(); // <-- here

         bootbox.dialog({

         // <snip...>

         });
     });
```

Comment: Isn't possible to hide the div after success ajax query ?